# Android Studio ToggleButton Check Problem

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

I'm working on creating an application with Java. In one of the screens, I've got 4 checkboxes, where if they are **checked**, the user is awarded with 15 points, and if they are not, no points are given. I've got the following code to check whether the **ToggleButton** is checked or not (taken from the Android Developers documentation):

```
fg_reflect_checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            reflectpoints += 15;
            ((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setReflectPoints(reflectpoints);
        } else {
            reflectpoints += 0;
            ((DataSite) getActivity().getApplication()).setReflectPoints(reflectpoints);
        }
    }
});
```

This works just fine, if I tap on the toggle, a **tick** is added, and I am awarded with 15 points. However, if I tap it again to remove the tick, and then tap it back on to add it again, it adds 15 more points, totaling to 30.

This is a problem for me, since a user can accidentally tap on a toggle to remove the tick, and then tap it again to correct his / her mistake. He / she will not be awarded 15 points, but 30.

I've tried implementing a second check within the if clause but it didn't work. I would essentially like to check if the tick is there, and avoid the score being registered twice, or more times with every tap. Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just subtract 15 if a checkbox becomes unchecked?

Comment: Oh my...it worked! I've tried it before but I put the subtraction on `else`. I have added an `else if` clause thanks to your comment. Cheers, don't know how I missed that one!